# Invoking an Interface method using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to invoke an Interface method and I have this error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I try using ConstructorInfo too and also have error. Please help.

```
public class ClassA 
{ 
       private void MethodA(int num, ClassC result)
       {
       } 
}
public interface InterfaceB 
{ 
       ClassC MethodB(int num); 
}
internal class ClassB 
{ 
      public ClassC MethodB(int num)
      {
      } 
}

Type typClassA = Type.GetType("ClassA");
Type typInterfaceB = Type.GetType("InterfaceB");
MethodInfo methodB = typInterfaceB.GetMethod("MethodB", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); // Error lies here
ClassC result = (ClassC) methodB.Invoke(typInterfaceB, new object[]{num});

MethodInfo methodA = typClassA.GetMethod("MethodA", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
methodA.Invoke(typClassA, new object[]{num, result});
```

The actual code for ClassB is not declared as "public ClassB : InterfaceB" but include more classes and ClassB is internal access. See edited codes. Apology for changing the codes so many times as I don't know how to simplify this scenario.

Comment: what programming language you use?

Comment: and why you try get `Static` method? Can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: C#, actually I was using Instance. Sorry I have not changed it back.

Comment: Not clear at all. Do you have an instance of the class which implements InterfaceB.MethodB?

Comment: Yes. Let's call it ClassB and implements InterfaceB.MethodB. Note: I also change the ClassB in the code to ClassC for clarity.

Comment: Would it be possible to post some code that actually compiles? I'm having trouble understanding your intent here, meaning that I can't really attempt an answer to the question. For a start, you could add the 'class' declaration to the classes, and fill in the return types to all the methods...

Comment: @Nicholas, so do you have an instance of the class which implements InterfaceB.MethodB? or you have a class with method with same name in interface?

Answer (score 2):

You have to give fully qualified name for class . please observe the below example

```
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    interface IA
    {
        void Print();
    }

    class A : IA
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication10.A");
            type.GetMethod("Print").Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(type, null), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# does **not** use [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). 
Therefore in order to actually implement an interface method, you will have to **declare** that your class implements that interface:

```
public class ClassB : InterfaceB
```

There are other problems in your code:

```
Type typInterfaceB = Type.GetType("InterfaceB"); // unless you have no namespace at all, you need to specify the fully qualified name

// Probably you got an NRE because of above issue here
MethodInfo methodB = typInterfaceB.GetMethod("MethodB", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); 

// this does not work, because the first argument needs to be an instance 
// try "new ClassB()" instead
ClassC result = (ClassC) methodB.Invoke(typInterfaceB, new object[]{num});
```

Comment: The actual code is not public class ClassB : InterfaceB. It's much complicated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't quite understand what you want, but i think you need something like this

```
public interface InterfaceB 
{
    int method(int d);
}
public class ClassB:InterfaceB
{
    int a = 10;
    public int method(int d)
    {
        return a + d;
    }
}


var b = new ClassB();
var mi = typeof(ClassB).GetInterface("InterfaceB").GetMethod("method");
var res = mi.Invoke(b, new object[] { 10 }); // res == 20
```

**UPDATE**
yet another variant

```
public interface InterfaceB 
{
    int method(int d);
}
public class ClassB:InterfaceB
{
    int a = 10;
    public int method(int d)
    {
        return a + d;
    }
}


var b = new ClassB();
var mi = typeof(InterfaceB).GetMethod("method");
var res = mi.Invoke(b, new object[] { 10 }); // res == 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to invoke a method on an object of type `System.Type`, and not on the object that implements that interface.

The first parameter of `MethodInfo.Invoke` is the instance of the object you want to invoke the method on... you are using an instance of a `System.Type` object, and not one of `ClassA` or `ClassB`

Answer (score 0):

All your methods are *instance* (not *static*) methods, so you *have to create instances* to call them, and pass these *instances* to `Invoke`, for instance:

```
  // Let's call MethodA from ClassA

  Object instanceA = new ClassA();
  MethodInfo methodA = instanceA.GetType().GetMethod("MethodA", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

  // Pay attention to 1st argument - instanceA
  methodA.Invoke(instanceA, new object[]{num, result});  

  ...

  // Since ClassB doesn't implement InterfaceB, the only option 
  // is to call MethodB of ClassB
  Object instanceB = new ClassB();
  MethodInfo methodB = instanceB.GetType().GetMethod("MethodB", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

  ClassC result = (ClassC) (methodB.Invoke(instanceB, new object[]{num}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your object has needed method then you can use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd264741.aspx) and write like this:

```
var result = (yourObject as dynamic).YourMethod("SomeParam");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IGetNames
{
    string GetFirstName();
    string GetMiddleName();
}
public class GetNames : IGetNames
{
    public string GetFirstName()
    {
        return "First Name";
    }
    public string GetMiddleName()
    {
        return "Middle Name";
    }
}
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
Type _Interface = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication2.IGetNames");
Type _Class = Type.GetType("ConsoleApplication2.GetNames");
InterfaceMapping GetInterfaceMap = _Class.GetInterfaceMap(_Interface);
MethodInfo methodInfo =  GetInterfaceMap.TargetMethods[0];
object str =  methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(GetInterfaceMap.TargetType), null);
}
```

Comment: It’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially relevant for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?